# WCF Test Clinet - Can't Edit Config File

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2008, wcf-client

We are currently experiencing an issue that requires the client endpoint configuration file to be modified but can't find a way to do this in the WCF test Client. Is there a way to modify the Config file in the WCF Test Client?

I have read that you should be able to right click and select edit but this option is not available.

Running Visual Studio 2008 (without SP1 - please don't ask why)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To edit the client config in WcfTestClient, right click on the Client Config below the listed service and select "Edit with SvcConfigEditor".  Is the "Edit with SvcConfigEditor" greyed out or missing when you right click on Client Config?

Here is a link on more information about WcfTestClient for .Net 3.5:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb552364(v=VS.90).aspx

**Update**

The "Edit with SvcConfigEditor" is added in SP1, but you can try the following to make manual changes:

From http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/dde72fbe-e741-48fd-a9e1-253800d5227a/ Herve Roggero suggested this:

Well, I was facing a similar challenge. There is a manual way to do this until the tool gets updated.

Start the client interface (WcfTestClient.exe) with the WCF Service HTTP

Expand the service and right-click on the Web.Config (do not double-click - this will load the config file)

Click on Copy Full Path

Go to the file and edit the configuration sections you need to change (buffer limits, dns identity for https...)

You can now start using the tool with a modified config file.

Unfortunately everytime you restart the tool a new config file gets generated in a different folder. So this is a manual step. Still it helped me test an HTTPS endpoint that required changing the config file.

Hope this helps

Comment: I wish I could upload a screen but until I earn at least 10 rep points im limited to words. When I right click on Config File, methods, Service contract or service URL the only option I get is "copy".

Comment: @Boden Could you put a link in your comment to a free image hosting url?

Comment: try this - http://cid-0165dcb453d62279.photos.live.com/self.aspx/Public/WCFTESTClient.JPG

Comment: Ok, I think I have something for you. According to this post: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wcf/thread/dde72fbe-e741-48fd-a9e1-253800d5227a/ the "Edit with SvcConfigEditor" option wasn't enabled until SP1 ... but some suggested a manual method to change it.  I'm adding the suggestion from the post to my solution because its long.

Comment: Thanks Robert, you have been a great help.